# Declare $row for two tables

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to echo data from two tables to one variable. Here is the code that I have so far:

```
$sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM News ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10"; 
$sqlCommand3 = "SELECT * FROM Users ORDER BY id"; 

$query = mysql_query($sqlCommand) or die(mysql_error());
$query3 = mysql_query($sqlCommand3) or die(mysql_error());

$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($count > 1) {
    $News .= "";

    // How do I add the query3 here?? along side the already existing one
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

        // some of the $row here are from query one and some are from query 3
        $News .= "<a href=\"news?id=".$row['id']."\"><div class=\"news-post\"> <img src=\"".$row['author']."\"><p>".$row['author']."</p>  <h2>".$row['title']."</h2></div></a>";
    } // close while
```

Comment: Are those two tables related?  If so, have you considered using a JOIN query?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't the right way to go about it, instead try using a [SQL join](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/).  In this case, you'll want a unique `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

```
SELECT * FROM News
FULL OUTER JOIN USERS
ON News.id = Users.id
WHERE News.id IS NULL
OR Users.id IS NULL;
```

This should give you all rows containing all columns from both tables. Depending on the actual relationship, you may want some different kind of join (refer to previous link)..but this seems like what you were trying to accomplish in your example.

**Warning:** you are using the `mysql_*` extension which has been [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php#migration55.deprecated.mysql).  Please use either [`mysqli_*`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 0):

Your User table should be linked to the News table by a oneToMany association.
So a user writes a news and a new is written by a user.
And you need to add a join in your SQL query.

```
$sql = 'SELECT u.username, n.* FROM News n JOIN User u ON n.user_id = u.id';
```

Then, you while only have to execute one SQL statement and display the result in you HTML.

Have look to this [website](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

Comment: Only note, is to find a [better resource than W3Schools](http://www.w3fools.com/).  It can be tough sometimes since they rank so well with SEO.